# Why $\sum_{i=1}^{k} \frac{1}{p^i} = \frac{p^{-k}-1}{1-p}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, arithmetic, geometric-series

I have the statement:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{k} \frac{1}{p^i} = \frac{p^{-k}-1}{1-p}$$

without a clear step explanation why.

I've tried expanding the LHS and rewriting the RHS, but I don't see it yet.

$$\sum_{i=1}^{k} \frac{1}{p^i}= ? =\frac{p^{-k}-1}{1-p}$$

I'd appreciate an intermediary step "?" to help understand the result.

Answer (score 4):

Quoting from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Derivation):

> $$\sum_{k=1}^{n} ar^{k-1} = a\ \frac{1-r^n}{1-r}.$$
>
> To derive this formula, first write a general geometric series as:
>
> $$\sum_{k=1}^{n} ar^{k-1} = ar^0+ar^1+ar^2+ar^3+\cdots+ar^{n-1}.$$
>
> We can find a simpler formula for this sum by multiplying both sides
> of the above equation by $1 − r,\ $ and we'll see that:
>
> \begin{align} (1-r) \sum_{k=1}^{n} ar^{k-1} & = (1-r)(ar^0 +
>  ar^1+ar^2+ar^3+\cdots+ar^{n-1}) \\  & = ar^0 +
>  ar^1+ar^2+ar^3+\cdots+ar^{n-1} - ar^1-ar^2-ar^3-\cdots-ar^{n-1} - ar^n
>  \\  & = a - ar^n \end{align}
>
> since all the other terms cancel. If $r\neq1,\ $ we can rearrange the
> above to get the convenient formula for a geometric series that
> computes the sum of n terms:
>
> $$\sum_{k=1}^{n} ar^{k-1} = a\ \frac{1-r^n}{1-r}.$$

Comment: Is latex/mathjax copied from wikipedia or did you have to edit it yourself?

Comment: I copied it first (from wikipedia "edit") and then deleted some bits and added dollar signs...

Comment: Ok I see now what you mean. [+1]

Answer (score 2):

You simply apply the formula for the sum of a geometric series:
$$x+x^2+\dots+x^k=x\bigl(1+x+\dots+x^{k-1}\bigr)=x\,\frac{x^k-1}{x-1},$$
substitute $\dfrac1p$ to $x$ in this formula and simplify.

Comment: A nice shortcut! Good enough!

Answer (score 1):

This is a geometric series. **Hint:** write
$$S=a+ar+ar^2+...+ar^N$$
and then multiply it by the common factor $r$ to obtain
$$rS=ar+ar^2+...+ar^{N+1}.$$
What you get if you substract one equation from the another one?